# c# Using strings on the outside of Blocks to edit it

Tags: c#, string, forms, visual-studio-2015, desktop-application

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    string aaxe = null;
    string apick = null;
    string asho = null;
    string acan = null;
    string aknife = null;
    string akey = null;
    string atre = null;
```

When I click on the Axe(`aaxe`). To edit the string of `atre` to "y" instead of null.
But when I try to do that it doesn't find `atre` inside of the `aaxe` block.
So how do I fix that?

```
public void Axe_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (aaxe == null)
    {
        richTextBox1.AppendText("You Don't Have An Axe\r\n");
    }

    if (aaxe == "y")
    {
        richTextBox1.AppendText("You Used your Axe\r\n");
    }
}
```

And here's the "`atre`" code

```
    public void Treasure_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (atre == null)
        {
            richTextBox1.AppendText("You Haven't Found the Treasure Yet!\r\n");
        string aaxe = "y"
```

And it can't find `aaxe`!

```
        }
        if (atre == "y")
        {
            richTextBox1.AppendText("You Found The Treasure!!!\r\n");
            richTextBox1.AppendText("The End Of The Adventure!");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Sorry I cannot say more based on the code you posted, but you should always declare your variables at the highest scope you need them (but not higher).  If you declare them outside the brackets, they should definitely be accessible inside.  But if you declare them inside the brackets, they will be local to inside the brackets and will not exist outside the brackets.

Comment: @WDS Within the class of course ;)

Comment: Where is the variable aaxe set? I do not see it.

Comment: Woops forgot the "`atre`" code by here it is

Comment: @ben I set it to null, its a string

Comment: In the second to bottom code box you are re-declaring it as a string.  Delete the word 'string' there.

Comment: so set it to `aaxe = "y"`?

Comment: Success!!! thanks WDS @wds

Comment: I commented what I did almost exactly the same time Ben posted the full answer below.  Please make sure and mark his as accepted.

Comment: @WDS I did, Thanks everyone who helped me. Time to code!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're re-declaring the variable. That's your issue. When you declare a variable, you can set the type:

```
string aaxe = null;
string atre = null;
```

When you *call* a variable, you only need to call it by the variable name:

```
aaxe = "y";
```

Like so:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    // Set the variables here
    string aaxe = null;
    string atre = null;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void Treasure_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (atre == null)
        {
            richTextBox1.AppendText("You Haven't Found the Treasure Yet!\r\n");
            // When you call a variable, you don't need to add the 'string' type. 
            aaxe = "y"
        }
        if (atre == "y")
        {
            richTextBox1.AppendText("You Found The Treasure!!!\r\n");
            richTextBox1.AppendText("The End Of The Adventure!");
        }
    }

    public void Axe_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Then, when you check the value of aaxe, it will = "y".
        if (aaxe == null)
        {
            richTextBox1.AppendText("You Don't Have An Axe\r\n");
        }
        if (aaxe == "y")
        {
            richTextBox1.AppendText("You Used your Axe\r\n");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You declare the variable aaxe twice in different scopes : One is the member level and the other local variable.

Please change the second string aaxe to aaxe = "y"; without string type.

```
 string aaxe = "y";
```

to

```
  aaxe = "y";
```